# Build C/C++ Executables for android using NDK failed

Tags: android, android-ndk

t_proj.c as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

my Android.mk as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE   := t_proj
LOCAL_SRC_FILE := t_proj.c

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

While compiling with `ndk-build`, I get the following error:

```
[armeabi] Executable     : t_proj
/usr/local/Cellar/android-ndk/r10e/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o:crtbrand.c:function _start: error: undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/Users/[USER]/t_proj/obj/local/armeabi/t_proj] Error 1
```

Comment: `android-3`? Are you really building for Android 1.5?

Comment: default used `android-3`, and I am using `android-21` same as it

Answer (score 1):

Try amending `Android.mk`:

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := t_proj.c`